# Flash get a data from object data or from url?

Tags: flash, variables

I am very new to this and I want some help. I couldn't even provide you enough code since I don't know how to start.

I want to create an mp3 player and I want to load the mp3 file using the url variable.

Let say I have this mp3player.swf and by loading the files it should not directly setup in the swf player but instead, it should looks like this one.

```
  <object data="mp3player.swf?streamingFile=/path/to/stream.mp3">....</object>
```

But I don't really know what code or what functions of flash I will use in my mp3player.
So I guess the placeholder as my variable is the "streamingFile" and through this variable, I can directly play the mp3 file.

Please provide me a tips, I've been searching but I can't find any of those that suits to my needs or maybe you have a reference site for this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you need to use [FlashVars](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html).